# Ajax Success Function and Unique Div ids

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

This is really a two part question.  I have a while loop that runs through an SQL query and prints off as many articles as it finds in the database.

```
    <div class='dislike_box'>
       <a href='#' class='counter'>
       <img src='img/dislike.png' class='vote'></a>
       <p class='vote_text'>$dislike_num</p>
        <p style='color: #EC2800;'>$dislike_username</p>
    </div>

    <script>
        $('.dislike_box a').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
           url: 'vote.php?vote=dislike&title=$title', 
           success: function(result){
            $('.dislike_box p.vote_text').text('Got it.');
        }});
    });

    </script>
```

1. The script is in another file.  The issue is when the anchor tag is clicked all of the divs p.vote_text on the page gets updated, when I only want to update that specific one.
2. My second question is, is there a way in the php file to reutrn a value that makes the 'success' function in the ajax method not execute, say for instance they aren't logged in so I don't want them to vote.

Thanks for any help, and I will give credit to a correct answer.  Also if you need more info I will be happy to provide it.

I have solved question 2 with returning:

```
         header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Booboo');
         header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
         die(json_encode(array('message' => 'ERROR', 'code' => 1337)));
```

on fail.

*EDIT* 
I have everything working properly except when I run this:

```
  $('.dislike_box a').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var title = $(this).data('title');
    alert("You don't like: "+ title);
    $.ajax({
    url: 'vote.php?vote=dislike&title=title', 
    success: function(result){
        $('.dislike_box p.vote_text').text('Dont Like it.');
    }});
});
```

the alert box displays the correct title but the php function is literally putting the string "title" into the database instead of the variable.

Comment: To have it update a specific spot, you will have to reference the `$(this)` since you are using a class. `$(this)` designates what you are currently acting on.

Comment: As for question two, you just send back a value (I use json) that your success interprets and an action so you know what steps in js take next. You are not doing anything with `result`, that is where you tell js to do something. Lets say your php returns `{"success":true}`, then use `JSON.parse(result)` to get the value to see it worked.

Comment: in a while loop? what? that would mean you're binding this event n times. very bad. the javascript portion only needs to happen once.

Comment: each article has its own ajax function ? Please don't. create a separated js file with a function with parameters

Comment: Oh man, I just noticed what @pszaba is saying, *"...and own ajax function.."* definitely don't do that.

Comment: Yea I have moved it to another file.  Thanks.

Comment: @Rasclatt do you think you could show me how to properly use the $(this) functionality I am away of what $(this) does I'm just not sure how to implement it

Comment: I have moved my script to another page, my issue is how do I tell that function in the other page which $title variable to use, is there a way to pass it from the anchor?

Comment: you can use jQuery.data(), like <a href='#' class='counter' data-title="$title"> and the jq part is  $('.counter_maybe_or_this').data('title')

Comment: Appreciate @pszaba

Comment: I used your code my issue is that it is literally entering the string "title" into the database instead of the php variable.

Comment: js variables are not parsed in strings so you probably want something like this
url: 'vote.php?vote=dislike&title=' + title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The way you select the .vote_text is wrong:  .dislike_box p.vote_text selects ALL the boxes. Your click function should accept a param so that the a's parent can be targeted.

Let's imagine that you number your questions via id:

the action on your action button should be:

```
     $('.dislike_box a').click(function(event){
            var parent_question = $(this).closest('.sql_questions');
            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
               url: 'vote.php?vote=dislike&title=$title', 
               success: function(result){
                $(parent_question).text('Got it.');
            }});
     });
```

2. It's a PHP question. For the answer to be "fail" you should return a 403 Forbiden access error (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403) or some other error.

Comment: and get familiar with the $('#static_dom').on('click', '.can_be_dynamic', function({ alert('Hi') }));

Comment: is there a way to pass $title variable to the ajax function ?

Comment: @Waggoner_Keith you can probably just use a `data` field to extract the `$title` like `<div class='dislike_box' data-title="<?php echo $title; ?>">` then use `var getTitle = $(this).data('title');`There are lots of ways to pass this to ajax.

Comment: Ok i have <a href='#' class='counter' data-title='$title'> and in js I have    var title = $('.counter').data('title');
  $.ajax({
  url: 'vote.php?vote=dislike&title=$title',  But that is just putting the string 'title' into my database not the actualy variable.

Comment: So I am trying to pass the $title variable over to jquery with data-title='$title' and then get it in jquery with var getTitle=$(this).data.('title') then pass it to the php url with url: 'vote.php?vote=dislike&title=title' but then php just get the title variable as the literally string 'title'.

Comment: correction passing the jquery variable to the php function with url: 'vote.php?vote=dislike&title=getTitle'

Comment: Then the php function is literally putting "getTitle" into the database. when I alert the getTitle variable though in the jquery function I am getting the correct title so I think it just has to do with the way I'm passing it to php